# java.io.IOException: Len error. A message from /172.19.0.1:36208 with advertised length of 1195725856 is either a malformed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I use https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka . File `docker-compose.yml` on Windows 10 pro x64, with Docker for Windows 4.8.2 (79419)

[image]

```yaml
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.2
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

then

```
docker-compose up
```

error

```
java.io.IOException: Len error. A message from /172.19.0.1:36208 with advertised length of 1195725856 is either a malformed message or too large to process (length is
```

Full log: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/donhuvy/2fb3cd4334aea69f6709b6486f7af0aa/raw/b160106d4da7748a0c0379ae6e89066174c60e76/docker_log.txt

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Changed tags since the error is from Zookeeper, not Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Move `docker-compose.yml` to a short folder path (for example, `D:\`).

Comment: The filepath shouldn't matter how network communication happens between containers. Note: You don't need a port mapping to the host from Zookeeper.